# Ruby installation in project with Sass

Tags: css, ruby, installation, sass, exe

I was wondering if someone could help me with the following problem:

I have a web project in visual studio and I am using SASS for styling. I use Grunt to execute SASS and compile the .scss files to .css files. But for this to work Ruby must be installed on my system together with a SASS module. When someone else does a checkout of my project they cannot run SASS if they don't have ruby intalled on their system with this SASS module.

Is it possible to add a ruby installation (executable) with the SASS module to my project so that when someone else does a checkout of my project they can run SASS without having ruby installed on their system.

Thx in advance for any help, also this is my first question on stackoverflow ever, tips are welcome.

(Things I have run into but will probably not work are: Less, node-sas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to easily add a Ruby installation executable with your project. And I don't think you should.

Have a look on [libSass](http://sass-lang.com/libsass), which was created and maintained by Sass authors. This library allow non-Ruby users to compile Sass. You've got plenty wrappers for various languages, like .NET, Java, JS, PHP, Python...

I think this could be a workaround that fit your needs.

Comment: The node-sass I ran into earlier actually uses libSass. I'd prefer using the Ruby compiler, but im going to try out this workaround and see if it runs into any problems. For now at least it seems like using LibSass/node-Sass results in practically the same css files as when using the Ruby compiler.

Thank you for your answer